# child_process.exec('start cmd') doesn't include user path

Tags: node.js, windows, terminal

`child_process.exec('start cmd')`

Doesn't include user path variables. The system path is there though

How can I get both paths included?

[image]

This is causing stuff from my user path to not be found when I'm using the spawned cmd window

Comment: It works for me , I am able to get PATH variable after opening cmd

Comment: @Sumeet Are you sure you're getting the stuff from your user path, and not just the system path? I did `echo %path%` and it had system path stuff, but not my user path stuff